# Eclipse, Git and Bitbucket - Can't push - Error 401 Unauthorized

Tags: eclipse, git, bitbucket, egit, git-push

I have a problem with Bitbucket and EGit. I created a new repository on BitBucket and also a new project in Eclipse. When I try to push a commit, I get the following error message:

```
Can't connect to any repository: https://bitbucket.org/MyName/MyProject.git 
(https://bitbucket.org/MyName/MyProject.git: 401 Unauthorized)
```

I also tried `https://MyName@bitbucket.org/MyName/MyProject.git` but I got the same error. After creating the commit, I pushed by using the command line with `git push` and it **worked without a problem**. After that I tried pushing with Eclipse and EGit but I got the same error again. I checked my account name and password multiple times.

Do I need to configure EGit in some way to make it possible to push from Eclipse to BitBucket? A month ago I always pushed to a repository on a different host from Eclipse with EGit without a problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It depends on your version of Eclipse and Egit.
With the very latest Neon, there is a [thread reporting the same issue](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/1081631/), and a ticket opened: [bug 501000](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=501000).

There is a fix in progress: [Change 82187: "EGit Authenticator prevents login dialog"](https://git.eclipse.org/r/#/c/82187/).
It is already [merged into master](http://git.eclipse.org/c/mpc/org.eclipse.epp.mpc.git/commit/?id=39b391c52f548db09e8b050a27c457bd22818632) (also on the GitHub mirror:[commit 39b391c](https://github.com/eclipse/epp.mpc/commit/39b391c52f548db09e8b050a27c457bd22818632) and [commit 10c65c7](https://github.com/eclipse/epp.mpc/commit/10c65c77e99d37a5191f3ed1a50b1736cd560493).
[Change 82539](https://git.eclipse.org/r/#/c/82539/) also just got [merged 3 days ago](http://git.eclipse.org/c/simrel/org.eclipse.simrel.build.git/commit/?id=c4c29a8c85be41c5c3a4b5f5caaa9018a5e3f268).

So Marketplace Client Project project repository 1.5.2 should include the fix.
Actually, it is called [1.5.1a](http://download.eclipse.org/mpc/releases/1.5.1a/), but you can use http://download.eclipse.org/mpc/releases/1.5.2. as an url.

> If you are using Eclipse Neon you may also install EPP Marketplace Client from the Neon repository. Click `Help > Install New Software`, type "`neon`", select the Neon repository URL, select `Collaboration > Eclipse EPP Marketplace Client` and click `Install`.

There is also a fix in progress for EGit itself: [change 82295](https://git.eclipse.org/r/#/c/82295/).

Comment: Thanks a lot, installing _EPP Marketplace Client_ fixed the problem. I used the latest Neon release indeed.