# TFS-Git - An exception occurred during push on URI: 401 Unauthorized

Tags: eclipse, git, tfs

I'm getting an error while pushing the git project to master on Eclipse. I am using Eclipse Neon.1 and trying to connect to TFS-Git repository. I am able to push and pull from the same repo using cli tools but eclipse troubles me. Here is the error message

> An exception occurred during push on URI
>   https://tfs.[mydomain].com/tfs/Test_Collection_Report/_git/TFS_GIT_Training:
>   https://tfs.[mydomain].com/tfs/Test_Collection_Report/_git/TFS_GIT_Training:
>   401 Unauthorized

Using the Team Explorer plugin for Eclipse, I am able to connect to the repository. I have followed the fix mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39924175/eclipse-git-and-bitbucket-cant-push-error-401-unauthorized), but no luck yet. Any idea whats blocking me from pusing to git through eclipse? Here are my guess,

1. Windows git and EGit conflict
2. Eclipse not considering my credentials while connecting to git.

Any suggestion on how to fix it?

Comment: If you can connect to the repository using Team Explorer plugin, then the issue maybe related to your local eclipse more. Not related to TFS. And what's the result if you using console  command ?

Comment: How do you connect to TFS Git Repo? Can you share the steps? I cannot see this issue at my side.